# Minus sign for incoming antifermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, conventions, feynman-diagrams, fermions

In his *Diagrammatica, The Path to Feynman Diagrams* (Cambridge University Press, 1994; §4.5 "Quantum Electrodynamics", p. 88), M. Veltman reports the following Feynman rule for *incoming* antifermions:

$$
-V^{-1/2}\overline{u}^{\lambda}(\vec{k}),\qquad \lambda=3,4.
$$

I am struggling with that minus sign in front, which is unique to incoming antifermions.

I have consulted different books, including Peskin-Schroeder's *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*, Greiner-Reinhardt's *Field Quantization*, but I have found nothing. These and other references do not even discuss the prescription in question.

B. de Wit and J. Smith only suggest that:

> [...] the overall sign factor [of a sum of diagrams] is amiguous, but as we are only interested in the absolute value of the total amplitude this aspect is not relevant. (*Field Theory in Particle Physics*, 1986; §5.1 "Feynman rules for spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ fields", p. 179)

I can be convinced of the practical irrelevance of such a sign, but this consideration dodges the problem from a theoretical standpoint.

Veltman actually does provide a clarification for the incoming antifermions sign rule: it has to do with Fermi-Dirac statistics and the relative sign between diagrams which differ by exchanges of fermionic legs. As far as I can tell, it should be intended as a shortcut when the emergence of the sign difference between diagrams is not accounted for by a simple rearrangement of creation-annihilation operators inside the operator string of an S-matrix element. Nevertheless, I do not thoroughly understand the example the author presents, or at least I am not quite sure to have got it. In the following, I try to discuss my interpretation of the example and my doubts on it.

Let $\psi$ be the Dirac field and denote with $a(\vec{p})$, $b(\vec{k})$ the annihilation operators for electrons and positrons, respectively (the polarization index is here dropped for notational ease).

Consider, for instance, the two diagrams drawn below on inspiration of *Diagrammatica*:

[image]

For this couple

> the relative minus sign [...] is formulated explicitly by the prescription that there is a minus sign for every incoming anti-fermion [...]. (*Diagrammatica*, p. 89)

It must be noticed that, according to Fermi-Dirac statistics and the usual convention of total anti-commutation between fermionic fields (though associated to distinguishable particles), it must hold that $\lvert \vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_2\rangle=-\lvert \vec{p}_2,\vec{p}_1\rangle$, where the first and second 3-momentum appearing in the ket specify for the state of a particle labeled by 1 and of a particle labeled by 2, respectively.

Now, considering how the operators are ordered inside the interaction Hamiltonian density of QED ($\mathcal{H}_I=-|e|\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi$, if the metric signature $(+,-,-,-)$ is adopted), one exctracts, for the diagram on the left (initial state: $\lvert \vec{p},\vec{q}\rangle$; final state: $\langle\vec{p}\,',\vec{k}\,'\rvert$)<sup>*</sup>:
$$
\begin{split}
&\langle\vec{p}\,',\vec{k}\,'\rvert\mathcal{H}_I\lvert \vec{p},\vec{k}\rangle\underset{\psi\text{ contains }a^\dagger, b}{\overset{\psi\text{ contains }a, b^\dagger}{\longrightarrow}} \langle\vec{p}\,',\vec{k}\,'\rvert a^\dagger (\vec{p}\,')b^\dagger (\vec{k}\,')b(\vec{k}) a(\vec{p})  \lvert \vec{p},\vec{k}\rangle=\\
&=\langle\vec{p}\,',\vec{k}\,'\rvert a^\dagger (\vec{p}\,')b^\dagger (\vec{k}\,')\lvert 0\rangle=\langle\vec{p}\,',\vec{k}\,'\rvert\vec{p}\,',\vec{k}\,'\rangle=1
\end{split}
$$

while for the one on the right (initial state: $\lvert 0\rangle$; final state: $\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rvert$):
$$
\begin{split}
&\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rvert\mathcal{H}_I\lvert 0\rangle\rightarrow\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rvert a^\dagger (\vec{p}\,')b^\dagger (\vec{k}\,')a^\dagger(\vec{p}) b^\dagger(\vec{k})  \lvert 0\rangle=\\
&=\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rvert a^\dagger (\vec{p}\,')\color{red}{(-a^\dagger(\vec{p})b^\dagger (\vec{k}\,'))}b^\dagger(\vec{k}) \lvert 0\rangle=-\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rvert \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rangle=-1,
\end{split}
$$

which indeed could also be obtained by transmuting $\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k}\,',\vec{k}\rvert$ into $\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k},\vec{k}\,'\rvert$, or any other permutation of 3-momenta inside this array.

Infact, one recalls that, in general, given two different particles with 3-momenta $\vec{p}\,'$ and $\vec{p}$, whose creation operators are $a_1^\dagger(\vec{p})$ and $a_2^\dagger(\vec{p}\,')$:
$$
\lvert \vec{p}, \vec{p}\,'\rangle = a_1^\dagger(\vec{p})a_2^\dagger(\vec{p}\,')\lvert 0\rangle=-a_2^\dagger(\vec{p}\,')a_1^\dagger(\vec{p})\lvert 0\rangle \color{red}{\ne \lvert \vec{p},\vec{p}\,'\rangle}.
$$

So, the appearance of a sign seems to be forced, but I am not quite convinced of two things:

1. Whether the way in which I exchanged fermionic legs is correct.
2. The arbitrariness of the ordering of 3-momenta in the ket-array: indeed, if I chose to represent the final state as $\langle \vec{p}\,',\vec{p},\vec{k},\vec{k}\,'\rvert$ from the beginning, I would have got $1$ instead of $-1$.

<sup>* The selection of the right momentum to be given as an argument to creation/annihilation operators so to make the S-matrix element non-vanishing has been implicitly carried out.</sup>